# jquery component for multiple usage

Tags: jquery, widget, components

I have to build something (I can't post the pic because I'm new here) which has 6 text fields for displaying data, some kind of progressbar with percentagetext, an areafield and some icons showing green or red statuslamps as a kind of jQuery widget component I guess but currently I've no clue how to start.

The widget should be used 32 times on one html site showing different orders and status of measurement devices. I would like to build one component in order to stay maintainable and just change, for example, the id of each component in order to request different devices. The requests will be made every 10-20 secs so there should be no overload for the components.

Currently I've no idea what could be the best way to build such a thing one time and use it multiple times on an html page. Looking around the web I've seen a lot of possibilities but no real example which helped me to get a clue how to start. Maybe someone knows an example or so which could be used for such a task, e.g. how to build some kind of widget and html markup and include it in a html page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too vague question. I think you have two separate tasks: 1st is display status, and 2nd is repeatedly request smth to do smth. 1st task is simple, just generate some html by your back-end script. For second use js setInterval.

Comment: Have tried to have a look at the jQuery progressbar (It's a part of jQuery UI)?

Comment: hi, i would like to use jquery ui widgets including progressbar, the thing is i would like to bundle them to some kind of component which i can place in lets say an 8x4 grid. each component should make a request (as yuri mentioned with setinterval) to a specified webservice which will provide the display data. of course i could hardcode the whole thing, although designen one piece an reuse it would make me much happier :D

Comment: http://sinthetic-motion.at/upload/frame1.jpg this is the component which i would like to design!